# Facebook comments plugin on html page not redirecting when user has to login to FB account

Tags: facebook-comments

Have implemented Facebook comments plugin. If a user is not signed into a Facebook account, after clicking the Comment button and loggin in to their account nothing happens unless the F5 key is pressed. Is this correct or do I need to do something.

When the Comment button is clicked the login screen says: Log in to use your Facebook account with . Then requests the login credentails.

I have added a login button which when pressed says "Log in to use your Facebook account with Comments." and then requests the login credentials.

This is an example of a page with the comments:
http://www.shahphoto.co.uk/wedding_photographers/wedding-photographer-cornwall-pervaiz-shah.html